# nativescript-vue application crashes on splash screen (only in iOS)

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Since one week i try to figure out what am i doing wrong.

I created a nativescript-vue application which works fine on android.
Now i have to run the same App on an iOS device.

In my first try i got any errors i figured out and successfully got my app build running on my simulator on my mac.
Now i have another problem. The Console logs said, my build was successfully and it start on the simulator as expected but it crashes at the splash screen (with no errors).

I build another fresh app according to the official constructions.
There was one bug i fixed and the app runs as expected.
I decided to transfer the files from my main application one by one until the problem occurs.
The strange thing is, the app was running and did not crash in splash screen until i rerun the command "tns run ios --bundle" a few minutes later.
Now the app crashes again without any errors.

I hope anyone could help me.

System:

macOS Catalina - version: 10.15.1

node: v13.2.0

xcode: 11.2.1

nativescript: 6.2.2

Comment: NativeScript Vue has issues with HMR, so it might not have cached all the code changes, on the second run with a clean build it probably did. You may repeat the steps once again, but try to run the project with HMR disabled this time. If possible, I may ask you to share the sample project where the crash can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It happens even after a clear build. I tried to remove node_module and platforms and reinstall them -> run tns prepare ios --release and the same happens.
At least i built it with xcode itself on my real device -> same happens.
Sry but i am not the owner and not allowed to share this project :/

Comment: Sorry I didn't ask you to try clean build. I suggested to create new project and apply new changes one by one like you did before but keep HMR disabled to make sure latest changes are applied. If its on splash screen, it may be the plugins you are loading or any operation you do on app component.

Comment: I'am grateful for your advice.
I figured out what causes the crash.
i had my Main.vue file in the app root directory. I moved it back to the components directory, restart the simulator and rerun tns run ios.
Now it works as expected.
Thanks a lot